# How can I shard MySQL database with Vitess using both Docker images?

Tags: mysql, docker, sharding, rdbms, vitess

I found out about Vitess which let you shard MySQL database.
I want to use the docker image of both MariaDB and Vitess but I'm not quite sure what to do next. I'm using CentOS 7.

I installed the images

```
docker pull mariadb
docker pull vitess/root
docker pull vitess/orchestrator
```

Log inside the vitess image

```
sudo docker run -ti vitess/root bash
```

As the website said, make build

```
make build
```

I set up the variables

```
export VTROOT=/vt
export VTDATAROOT=/vt/vtdataroot
```

The manual said it was in the home directory but in the image it's at root.

But after that I'm stuck. I laucnh zookeeper : ./zk-up.sh

```
Starting zk servers... Waiting for zk servers to be ready... Started zk servers. ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0412
00:31:26.378586     132 syslogger.go:122] can't connect to syslog
W0412 00:31:26.382527     132 vtctl.go:80] cannot connect to syslog:
Unix syslog delivery error Configured zk servers.
```

Oops, okay, let's continue...

./vtctld-up.sh for the web internace

```
Starting vtctld...
Access vtctld web UI at http://88bdaff4e181:15000
```

Obviously I cannot access that link since it's in docker on a headless server

./vttablet-up.sh suppose to bring up 3 vttablets, but MariaDB is in another docker, not yet started and if I open the file it is not apparent how to set it up.

Is there any MySQL or PostgreSQL sharding solution more easily installable?
Or how can I set this up?

(Docker noob here sorry)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you putting all the shards on the same physical hardware?  If so, is this just for testing?  I do not expect it to provide any performance benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiple container orchestrated, best bet is to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). You can define all the application dependencies as separate containers and network them to be accessible from each other.